# Designate Excel Data Connection ReadOnly

Tags: microsoft-excel, connection, read-only, read-write

I have an Excel file with a data connection to another Excel source which is referenced by several other reports. The data connection should be read only, but I cannot seem to setup the properties to do so - whenever the source file is open somewhere else, the data connection attempts to open the source as read-write. I have tried to enter ReadOnly=0,ReadOnly=TRUE, and ReadOnly=1, but nothing seems to be effective.

When the source file opens, it seems to interrupt my macro which executes as a timer. The connection string for my data connection is (with substituted paths):

`DSN=Excel Files;DBQ="Source File Path";DefaultDir="Directory Path";DriverId=1046;MaxBufferSize=2048;PageTimeout=5;`